# How to bind rows and sum the values of the columns

Tags: jupyter-notebook, data-binding, jupyter, bind

I have raw data with the data of violent crimes per year and gender divided by age categories. The dataframe has 13 rows and 27 columns. in the columns are years from 2015 to 2021, where each year is divided into "m_15" and "f_15" / "m_16" and "f_16", etc. "m" for male and "f" for female. in the rows are age categories. E.g. ">10", "11-14" to ">70" etc. Now I want to make two from the 12 age categories "0 - 29" and "30 to 70". The values of the columns should be summed up per year, so that I can compare the violent crimes for each year between the two newly created age categories. I would like to summarize the genders for each year, but that is probably too complicated, or I don't want to burden you with the effort of explaining it to me. I would be so glad for help! Chatgpt has failed after hours of chatting. By the way: I work with r jupyter notebooks.

Here's the dataset
[# https://www.bfs.admin.ch/bfs/de/home/statistiken/kriminalitaet-strafrecht.assetdetail.23225641.html]

I tried this after that I added in the initial table an "A" before every age categories from 0 till 29 and an "B" before the age categories 30 till >70. I know you shouldn't such things :-/

s_a <- data[grep("^A", data$alterskategorie), ]
neue_zeile_a <- c("alter_0_bis_29", "NA", colSums(s_a[, 2:27]))

s_b <- data[grep("^B", data$alterskategorie), ]
neue_zeile_b <- c("alter_20_bis_70", "NA", colSums(s_b[, 2:27]))

data <- rbind(S4, s_a, s_b)
data